# android speech recognition continously has no answer

Tags: android, voice-recognition

I want to create an android app that is waiting for speech of a specific keyword: when the user says this keyword, the service becomes ready to receive user voice commands. So I am searching for a continous speech recognizer,

Like this guy:

[Can I keep the speech recognizer listening indefinitely?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10182893/can-i-keep-the-speech-recognizer-listening-indefinitely)

Like this guy:

[Continuous Speechrecognition in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6027466/continuous-speechrecognition-in-android)

And this guy:

[Continuous Speech Recognition Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3148603/continuous-speech-recognition-android)

But seriously, there is not a clear answer for all those! Is there someone who are able to manage this? Is there a source code for that?

Comment: There is no need to ask duplicate questions here, you can just upvote other questions. Just another rant doesn't increase your chance to get a high quality anwer.

Answer (score -1):

Create a service and put your recognizer code there, it will work. You need the following in your intent

```
mSpeechRecognizerIntent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
    mSpeechRecognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,
                                    RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
    mSpeechRecognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_CALLING_PACKAGE, 
                                    this.getPackageName());
```

See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/RecognizerIntent.html for more info.